# mac administrator name and password

Tags: mac

Today the mac operation system popup to let me input the admin password and username. What should I do to find the admin password and username?

[image]

Comment: It’s not asking for the “admin” account, it’s asking for the username/password of an account with admin permissions.  Try entering your username and password.  If it fails, you need to ask the person who set up the Mac.

Comment: ALso do you know what kcproxy is and why it wants to alter your keychain.

Comment: @mmmmmm It's the component of the Keychain Access application which performs functions not allowed to regular or administrator accounts. Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53579/how-is-the-system-keychain-secured-in-os-x/115694#115694

Answer (score 2):

The dialog asks for *any* administrator account. Usually this is the first account created when installing macOS. If you don't remember, look into the **Users & Groups** section of **System Settings** (**Preferences** before macOS Ventura).